# Conditions on triangle inequality for integral kernel

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis

Consider $\int_RK(x,y)f(y)dy$,  where $K(x,y) \in M_+(R^2)$.

Let $L(t,s)$  be an iterated rearrangement of $K$. Let also $$
A(t,v)=\int_0^{1/v}L(1/t,s)ds,
$$
which is decreasing with $v$ and increasing with $t$.

What conditions on $L$ would guarantee that $A(t,v)\leq A(t,u)+A(u,v)$ with $v<u<t$?

For example, if $L=1/t+s$ the condition would be specified. I am looking for more general answer.